# How to sort a list on another list in lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Gived a list

```
[
{id:'i1',value:'v1'},
{id:'i3',value:'v3'},
{id:'i4',value:'v4'},
{id:'i2',value:'v2'},
{id:'i5',value:'v5'},
]
```

and another ordered id list

```
['i1','i2','i3','i4','i5']
```

get

```
[
{id:'i1',value:'v1'},
{id:'i2',value:'v2'},
{id:'i3',value:'v3'},
{id:'i4',value:'v4'},
{id:'i5',value:'v5'},
]
```

How to do this in lodash?

Comment: will these lists have always the same elements or could it be that they are 'off' on certain elements?

Comment: @Falk The lists may have any elements with a random `id`. Actually the data list is queried by id list from server. But the server can't promise the order of data will not be changed so I need to sort the data manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#sortBy) method and return the id's index position from the iteratee function

```
let sortedArray = _.sortBy(input, (v) => order.indexOf(v.id))
```

where

```
input = [
  {id:'i1',value:'v1'},
  {id:'i3',value:'v3'},
  {id:'i4',value:'v4'},
  {id:'i2',value:'v2'},
  {id:'i5',value:'v5'},
]
order = ['i1','i2','i3','i4','i5']
```

Comment: I think this is a better answer. Thank everyone.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `(v) => order.indexOf (v.id)` is called N times, and `order.indexOf` has complexity O(N).

Answer (score 0):

Convert Array to Object where key is `id` for better lookup. Replace each element in ordered list with actual value.

Edge case: the two array has the same elements

```
const foo = [
  {id:'i1',value:'v1'},
  {id:'i3',value:'v3'},
  {id:'i4',value:'v4'},
  {id:'i2',value:'v2'},
  {id:'i5',value:'v5'},
];

const ordered = ['i1','i2','i3','i4','i5'];

const fooMap = _.keyBy(f, 'id');

const orderedFoo = ordered.map(id => fooMap[id])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = ['i1','i2','i3','i4','i5'];
const arrObj = [
{id:'i1',value:'v1'},
{id:'i3',value:'v3'},
{id:'i4',value:'v4'},
{id:'i2',value:'v2'},
{id:'i5',value:'v5'}
]
const sortedArr = [];

_.map(arr, a => sortedArr.push(_.find(arrObj, ['id', a])));
console.log(sortedArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = ['i1','i2','i3','i4','i5'];
let arrObj = [
    {id:'i1',value:'v1'},   
    {id:'i3',value:'v3'},
    {id:'i4',value:'v4'},
    {id:'i2',value:'v2'},
    {id:'i5',value:'v5'}
]

console.table(arrObj);

arr.map(v => {
    arrObj.sort( v1 => { return v1.id == v ? true : false} )
})

console.table(arrObj);
```